# FACEBOOK JS SDK ::how to post an image on wall

Tags: javascript, facebook

i'm trying to post an image to my users's facebook wall once they hit a botton

i'm using javascript SDK but i have a problem, the image looks like a link in the wall ... but that's not what i want ... i want to post an image ... same as when you put an image link on your status text field and it turns to image

any help ?

```
FB.ui(
           {
             method: 'stream.publish',
             message: 'test',
             attachment :{ 
                    'name': 'i\'m bursting with joy', 
                    'href': ' http://bit.ly/187gO1', 
                    'caption': '{*actor*} rated the lolcat 5 stars', 
                    'description': 'a funny looking cat', 
                    'properties': { 
                        'category': { 'text': 'humor', 'href': 'http://bit.ly/KYbaN'}, 
                        'ratings': '5 stars' 
                    }, 
                    'media': [{ 
                            'type': 'image', 
                            'src': 'http://icanhascheezburger.files.wordpress.com/2009/03/funny-pictures-your-cat-is-bursting-with-joy1.jpg', 
                            'href': 'http://bit.ly/187gO1'}] 
                        },
             user_message_prompt: 'Share your thoughts about Connect'
           },
           function(response) {
             if (response && response.post_id) {
               alert('Post was published.');
             } else {
               alert('Post was not published.');
             }
           }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try [`FB.api()`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api) method:

```
var wallPost = {
    message : "testing...",
    picture: "http://url/to/pic.jpg"
};
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', wallPost , function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
  } else {
    alert('Post ID: ' + response);
  }
});
```

You can get a list of supported wall post params [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post) (see "Publishing").

Comment: but is there a way to UPLOAD IMAGE TO USER WALL ?

Comment: @From.ME.to.YOU well an image will be posted to a wall as an icon, not as a link. Is that what you need? What do you mean by upload?

Comment: @serg Hey, This is working fine but could you tell me how to post on friends wall?? I want to have a button which on click would "ask" the use whether to post the image on friends wall or not..

Answer (score 12):

To POST an image in user's wall use FB.api('/me/photos',...) instead of FB.api('/me/feed',...) and additionally access token is required.

Attached is the Code Example:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        var access_token =   FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];
        FB.api('/me/photos?access_token='+access_token, 'post', { url: IMAGE_SRC, access_token: access_token }, function(response) {
            if (!response || response.error) {
                //alert('Error occured: ' + JSON.stringify(response.error));
            } else {
                //alert('Post ID: ' + response);
            }
        });
    } else {
        //console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
    }
}, {scope: 'publish_stream'});
```

To Post on Friends Page: Enter the facebook user Id of friends in place of "/me" .

```
"/"+friends_user_id+"/photos" ....
```